# How do I add an transition animation by toggling a class?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have some elements need to be highlighted/unhighlighted conditionally.

So I have a class called `highlight` given to any element that need to be highlighted with a transition animation.

The problem is I can't animate it when the `highlight` class is removed.

Because any element could be highlighted so I couldn't find a specific selector for them.

I could do this but it just doesn't seem right to me:

```css
* {
  transition: background-color 1s;
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve it?

Here's a simplified example to demonstate my issue:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('body *')].forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', () => e.classList.toggle('highlight')));
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: red;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}
```

```html
<h2>Click anything to toggle highlight</h2>

<p>Hello</p>
<p>World</p>
<p>Thanks</p>
```

Comment: Well, if *anything* can be highlighted, what else do you want to do?

Comment: `I could do this but it just doesn't seem right to me`. I think that's the way that works for you. How does it not seem right? It's working

Comment: @HuyPhạm The issue with that approach is that I can't use transition for other selectors, ortherwise it'll just get overwritten.

Comment: @HaoWu Would you mind illustrate that (the `other selectors` problem) in your snippet? It's a bit mis-leading

Comment: @HuyPhạm Like if I have a `.container { transition: opacity 0.5s;  }`, then when the `.container` got class `highlight` the background won't be animated. Also the duration is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the logic differently

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('body *')].forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle('bg');
  e.target.classList.add('highlight'); /* always add highlight */
}));
/* remove highlight when the transition is done */
[...document.querySelectorAll('body *')].forEach(e =>
  e.addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) {
    e.target.classList.remove('highlight');
  })
);
```

```css
.highlight {
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

.bg {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>Click anything to toggle highlight</h2>

<p>Hello</p>
<p>World</p>
<p>Thanks</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! `transitionend` is definitely a better way to do this!